# How do javascript engines set properties on objects that have prototypes with a setter for that property?

Tags: javascript

I was always under the impression that when `[[set]]` (or is it `[[put]]`? is called on an object, the engine always assigns (or tries to) the property to that object, regardless of its prototype.

But today when I tried this

```
parent={
    set num(v){
        alert();
    }
}

obj=Object.create(parent);

obj.num=123;
```

it called the setter, so what really happens when the engine sets a property? Does it traverse the prototype chain to check if it has any setters first?

Comment: setters behave differently than normal properties; they grab name-conflicting own props away from the instance.

Comment: @dandavis Can you provide an example or some reference for that?

Comment: the answer has a decent example, but consider the converse: if it didn't trickle down to the proto, setters would be virtually useless on prototypes. it is a bit odd though, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engine does what it always does, which is to look for the property first on the instance and then, if not on the instance, in the prototype chain. If the property, wherever found and however defined, is defined with a setter, then the setter is executed. In your case, it finds the property in the prototype parent, and executes the setter, displaying the alert. Nothing is actually set. (Of course, if the property is not defined with a setter, then the value is set on the instance.)

If you want to actually create a property by the same name on the instance itself, you can do so using `defineProperty` (or the second argument to `Object.create`). This property will "shadow" (hide) the property by the same name on the prototype. The next time you attempt to set the property, the engine will find the property on the instance, and set it there (unless the property you define on the instance also has a setter, in which case that setter will be invoked).

Note that setters themselves do no setting. Whatever setting you might want to do, you will have to do yourself. For instance, you might want to set a proxy property such as `_num`, by saying `this._num = v`. Obviously, `this` here is the instance--even though the setter is defined on the prototype--and thus the `_num` property will be on the instance. If you try to do `this.num = v` inside the setter, you will end up with an infinite loop, because that will invoke the same setter again. `num` cannot be both a property based on getter/setter and a normal-valued property at the same time.

Consider the following:

```
parent = { set num(v) { alert(v); } };
obj = Object.create(parent);
obj.num = 44;  // alert

obj2 = Object.create(parent, { num: { value: 55 } });
obj2.num = 99  // proto ignored, no alert, simple assignment
```

Comment: Thanks, I just find it unusual that it would bother looking through the prototypes on an assignment because even if it did find the property in a property that wasn't a setter it only changes the property on the first instance. Does traversing the prototype chain on an assignment have any need besides for when there's a setter?

Comment: Yes, it would also honor a getter found on a property on the prototype if a property of the same name were not on the instance.